# Windows Forms' PictureBox with zooming and panning

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, bitmap, picturebox

My application needs control displaying bitmaps (jpg) but also zooming and panning them (so if you press mouse button you can 'move' zoomed picture inside frame)

What I did was placing panel at the Form, then pictureBox inside panel (anchored Top,Left).
So if I need zoom it I'm just executing below code from Zoom buttons events:

```
    private void ZommInOut(bool zoom) {
        int zoomRatio   = 10; // percent
        int widthZoom   = pBox.Width * zoomRatio /100;
        int heightZoom  = pBox.Height  * zoomRatio /100;

        if (zoom) {
            widthZoom   *= -1;
            heightZoom  *= -1;
        }

        pBox.Width  += widthZoom;
        pBox.Height += heightZoom;
    }
```

Works petty well. Image is zoomed, panel displaying scrollbars - so I have working simple panning functionality.

What is missing to me is **possibility to use mouse for panning** - I'd like to drag picture in any direction to see other part of picture (as eg Acrobat Reader does).
I've looked for the way to use **MouseMove** event and change scrollbars programically but I couldn't manage that.

Any suggestion(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`AutoScrollPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition.aspx) property in the MouseMove event.

You'll need to track the location of the MouseDown event and update AutoScrollPosition using an offset.

Comment: Whose MouseMove event you recommend for that? Form's or Panel's ?

Comment: @Maciej i don't think you're moving your mouse over the form. Your MouseMove ultimately will be captured by the PictureBox.

Comment: Sorry I've made mistake - I'd like to ask about Panel of PictureBox (not a Form). But you are right PB is right place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a control and drawing part of the image using Graphics.DrawImage - in this way you can control how the image is scaled (trilinear etc) and it will also use less memory. You can override OnMouseMove to get the mosue movements

Comment: You are probably right. But I've looked for something quick and codeless. Mentioned solution works to me.